# Not receiving segmentation fault from client after launching payload using nc from host (Docker)

Tags: linux, docker, server, dockerfile, client

I'm getting seg fault from running on the host.

[image]

But When I run from client using nc 0.0.0.0 8888
I'm not receiving the seg fault.

[image]

It is the ctf.xinetd file:

```
service ctf
{
    disable = no
    socket_type = stream
    protocol    = tcp
    wait        = no
    user        = root
    type        = UNLISTED
    port        = 9999
    bind        = 0.0.0.0
    server      = /usr/sbin/chroot
    # replace helloworld to your program
    server_args = --userspec=1000:1000 /home/ctf ./my_buf -d 2>&1
    banner_fail = /etc/banner_fail
    # safety options
    per_source  = 10 # the maximum instances of this service per source IP address
    rlimit_cpu  = 20 # the maximum number of CPU seconds that the service may use
    #rlimit_as  = 1024M # the Address Space resource limit for the service
    log_on_failure += USERID
}
```

It is the start.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# for pwn docker
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]
then
        echo "Usage: ./start.sh <docker name> <port number>"
else
        echo "Building docker"
        docker build -t $1 .
        echo "Running docker"
        docker run -d --name=$1 -p 0.0.0.0:$2:9999 $1 2>&1
fi
```

It is ctf.xinetd file:

```
service ctf
{
    disable = no
    socket_type = stream
    protocol    = tcp
    wait        = no
    user        = root
    type        = UNLISTED
    port        = 9999
    bind        = 0.0.0.0
    server      = /usr/sbin/chroot
    # replace helloworld to your program
    server_args = --userspec=1000:1000 /home/ctf ./my_buf -d 2>&1
    banner_fail = /etc/banner_fail
    # safety options
    per_source  = 10 # the maximum instances of this service per source IP address
    rlimit_cpu  = 20 # the maximum number of CPU seconds that the service may use
    #rlimit_as  = 1024M # the Address Space resource limit for the service
    log_on_failure += USERID
}
```

The Dockerfile is here:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils apt-transport-https && \
    apt-get install -y  lib32z1 xinetd && \
    apt-get -y dist-upgrade

RUN mkdir /home/ctf/

RUN useradd -m ctf

WORKDIR /home/ctf/

RUN cp -R /lib* /home/ctf

RUN rm -R /home/ctf/lib*
RUN cp -Rf /usr/lib* /home/ctf/

RUN mkdir /home/ctf/dev && \
    mknod /home/ctf/dev/null c 1 3 && \
    mknod /home/ctf/dev/zero c 1 5 && \
    mknod /home/ctf/dev/random c 1 8 && \
    mknod /home/ctf/dev/urandom c 1 9 && \
    chmod 666 /home/ctf/dev/*

RUN mkdir /home/ctf/bin && \
    cp /bin/sh /home/ctf/bin && \
    cp /bin/ls /home/ctf/bin && \
    cp /bin/cat /home/ctf/bin

COPY ./ctf.xinetd /etc/xinetd.d/ctf
COPY ./xinetedService.sh /xinetedService.sh
RUN echo "Blocked by ctf_xinetd" > /etc/banner_fail

RUN chmod +x /xinetedService.sh


COPY ./files/ /home/ctf/
RUN chown -R root:ctf /home/ctf && \
    chmod -R 750 /home/ctf && \
    chmod 740 /home/ctf/flag.txt
    

CMD ["/xinetedService.sh"]

EXPOSE 9999
```

How to edit this so that I also receive the seg fault error message from the host.